# How to get the view that corresponds to a url in Django (using the url)?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls, url-mapping

How can I get the view that a url maps to?
For example:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'^login/$', 'registration.views.Login'),)
```

How can I use the string `'login/'` to return `registration.views.Login`?

In case I'm not clear, I want to write a function that does the following (I'll call it `foo`):

```
>>> foo('login/')
<function Login at 0x010101010>
>>>
```

I'm writing a script that needs this. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, got it. This is how I did it:

```
>>> from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve
>>> foo = resolve('/login/')
>>> foo.func
<function Login at 0x010101010>
>>>
```

from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/urlresolvers/#resolve